# Is it possible to get a stable hyperparameter with unstable generalization error from a nested CV?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, experiment-design, hyperparameter, nested-models

I have created the following pipeline:

```
ridge = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler()), ('estimator', LinearSVR(random_state=7, dual=False, loss='squared_epsilon_insensitive'))])
```

Then I performed a grid search as follows:

```
gcv = GridSearchCV(ridge, params, scoring=inner_metric, cv=3, n_jobs=2, return_train_score=True, refit='neg_mean_absolute_error')
```

and a cross-validation:

```
results = cross_validate(gcv, X, y, scoring=outer_metrics, cv=5, n_jobs=3, return_train_score=True)
```

Thus I performed a nested CV.

However, when I checked the stability of my model with a stability plot, I got the following result (see picture) of an unstable generalization error with stable hyperparameters. I do not understand how this is possible...

Does it mean that my experimental setup is wrong, or is my estimator just inappropriate for handling this data? (I know that linear regression models should all be comparable in results, and my Lasso, ElasticNet, and Ridge models are all stable for both).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved: the plot made was defined over a grid that did not contain the optimal hyperparameters (but over a wrongly specified granulated grid). This initial grid was searched without a kfold (so cv=Kfold(3, shuffle=True) instead of cv=3). This led to an unstable result for the optimal hyperparameter. However, within this small grid, this hyperparameter set was consistently the best option, hence the hyperparameter plot for C (here denoted as alpha due to laziness) was stable even though this hyperparameter set would not consistently score well on unseen data.

Conclusion: always gridsearch using a shuffled kfold (and/or repeatedkfold):
cv= KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=my_rand_state)
gcv = GridSearchCV(ridge, params, scoring=inner_metric, cv=cv, n_jobs=2, return_train_score=True, refit='neg_mean_absolute_error')